Problem with substring in XML modify method
I want replace one value with another in XML value. What i need is to use a substring method:
UPDATE zamowienia_xml
SET tresc_xml.modify('
    replace value of (/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]
    with
    (
        if (1=1)
        then
            text(
                   substring(
                    "abcd",
                    1,
                    2)
                )
            )
        else
            text("0")
    )');

I simplify the sql, it is not making what it should, but it still has the same error. Why this doesn't work?
The error is:
[S0001][9303] Line 9: XQuery [zamowienia_xml.tresc_xml.modify()]: Syntax error near 'substring', expected ')'.

If someone what to see full sql, here can check:
UPDATE zamowienia_xml
SET tresc_xml.modify('
    replace value of (/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]
    with
    (
        if (substring(
                (/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1],
                string-length((/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]), 1) = "%"
           )
        then
            text(
                substring(
                    string((/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]),
                    1,
                    string-length((/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]) - 1
                )
            )
        else
            (/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]
    )');

Error is the same:
[S0001][9303] Line 12: XQuery [zamowienia_xml.tresc_xml.modify()]: Syntax error near 'substring', expected ')'.

I feel like i tried everything, but problem still exist.
And about the sql, what I want to achieve is to remove optional character "%" at the end.
UPDATE
This sql "almost works":
UPDATE zamowienia_xml
SET tresc_xml.modify
('
    replace value of (/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]
    with
    (
        if
        (
            substring
            (
                (/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1],
                string-length((/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]),
                1
            )
            = "%"
        )
        then
            substring
            (
                string((/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]),
                1,
                string-length((/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]) - 1
            )
        else
            (/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]
    )
')

Error:
[S0001][2210] Line 25: XQuery [zamowienia_xml.tresc_xml.modify()]: Heterogeneous sequences are not allowed: found 'xs:string' and 'text ?'

"If I replace the code after 'then' and 'else' with a simple string (for example, "123"), then it works. I understand that I need to type a string, not text. Is there any way to achieve that? In the previous code, I tried using text(...), but I encountered the error as shown before."
UPDATE 2
Casting not to text, casting to string and it works.
UPDATE zamowienia_xml
SET tresc_xml.modify
('
    replace value of (/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]
    with
    (
        if
        (
            substring
            (
                (/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1],
                string-length((/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]),
                1
            )
            = "%"
        )
        then
            substring
            (
                string((/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]),
                1,
                string-length((/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]) - 1
            )
        else
            string
            (
                (/zamowienie/profil_rabatowy/rabat/text())[1]
            )
    )
')


Probably easiest to create a column which does this substring thing and use sql:column inside the modify method to do the replacement. Or, even better, stop storing xml data and start normalizing your db

Among other things, the first snippet has too many ) characters.

Siggemannen, it's not commercial code, it's code for my studies :D

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
